# How to print Array values of custom Fields Meta?

Tags: customization, custom-field, array

How to print array values for custom field meta.

[image]

My code -

```
<?php $item = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'occupationalCategory', false); ?>
<?php print_r( $item[0]['occupationalCategory'] ); ?>;
<?php print_r( $item[1]['occupationalCategory'] ); ?>
```

Output - none

Comment: if you set third parameter of get_post_meta to true, it will also return an array. Then try just echo $item['0]

Comment: @anton It's working now. Check [Image](https://i.ibb.co/XYkv4Qc/Capture.jpg)  - how to print `US, 29.622, TX` because the array is not print with updated code.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the screenshot I assumed is var_dump of your $item
The code should look like

```
<?php $item = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'occupationalCategory', false); ?>
<?php print_r( $item['occupationalCategory'][0] ); ?>;
<?php print_r( $item['occupationalCategory'][1] ); ?>
```

$item contains array, with a element which key is 'occupationalCategory', this element points to other array with two elements